# How can i move a layout up on screen when another one above it is invisible in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this kind of structure in my screen and there's +/- button on my screen. On clicking - ListView inside LinearLayout_2 has been set Invisible and I want to move LinearLayout_3 up when the Listview is hidden/invisible.

```
<RelativeLayout Id="1">
  <LinearLayout Id="2">
       <ListView />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout Id="3" below="LinearLayout2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want visibility to be GONE

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE